# How to efficiently handle concurrent creation with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Data JPA, I have an Hibernate entity with a unique constraint on `name` and `context`:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private String name;
    @Id
    private String context;

// setter, getter, ID class, etc. omitted for brevity
}
```

whose creation logic looks a bit like this:

```
private final MyRepository repository;

@Transactional
public void createOrUpdate(String name, String context) {
  MyEntity entity = repository.findByNameAndContext(name, context)
      .orElseGet(() -> new MyEntity(name, context));

  entity.doSomething();

  repository.save(entity);
}
```

and where the repository method uses pessimistic locking:

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<...> {

  @Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
  MyEntity findByNameAndContext(String name, String context); 
}
```

This works ok in most cases until two separate threads try to create the same entity at the same time, by going both into the `orElseGet`. The first transaction finishing will be able to create a new row in database, but the second one will fail because of a `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

I understand why this fails, but I can't find an elegant way to handle that. The only solution I found is to retry the transaction when a `DataIntegrityViolationException` is raised.

Comment: Yes that would be the correct way. How do you think an elegant way should look like?

Comment: I don't know to be honest :p I am just wondering whether there is a magic Hibernate feature that I haven't found yet

Comment: No it's not. If you get a DataIntegrityViolationException the transaction will be rolledback. So the state of your Entity is not the same as in the database and you have to take care yourself.

Comment: Yes I understand, so that the `repository.findByNameAndContext` retrieves a managed entity on the second try

Comment: Yes it will get the entity created in the other transaction

Comment: I'm ok with the retry. If there are no other solutions I'll do it that way. Thank you Simon <3, I'll  write the answer myself after I'll implement it and mention your contribution